# How to LIMIT the fetching of the rows in the database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a query like this:

```
 Cursor _cursor = mbd.query(SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
            KEY_SYLLABICATION, KEY_WORD, KEY_PARTOFSPEECH, KEY_MEANING, KEY_SPEAKWORD},
            null, null, null, null, null, null);
```

I just simply want to limit the rows to fetch from the database.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), you pass the `LIMIT` clause as the eighth parameter to `query`:

```
Cursor _cursor = mdb.query(SQLITE_TABLE,
                           new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_SYLLABICATION,
                                          KEY_WORD, KEY_PARTOFSPEECH,
                                          KEY_MEANING, KEY_SPEAKWORD },
                           null, null, null, null, null,
                           "10");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
cursor = resolver.query(STORAGE_URI, projection,
                        Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME + "=?",
                        new String[] { folderName },
                        " _id asc limit " + num);
```

or try this

```
final String orderBy = Constants.TABLE_CONVERSATION_FIELD_DATE + " DESC";
final String limit= 10;

return db.query(table, columns, selection, selectionArgs, groupBy, having, orderBy, limit);
```